# What's the best practice for expressjs logging?

Tags: node.js, logging, express

I am building an application based on expressjs and I'd like to log all events in it. I could find winston, which seems to be cool. Anyway, I am looking for a way how to connect it to my expressjs app.

What I also want is logging inside the application. My reqeusts are not so simple, so I'd like to log everything inside my app (not only requests).

My current situation:

**server.js** (I'd like to log http requests on this level)

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var fs = require('fs');

// Post parser
app.configure(function(){
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
});

// Load routes
require('fs').readdirSync(__dirname + '/routes').forEach(function(file) {
    require(__dirname + '/routes/' + file)(app);
});

// 404: Not found
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    res.json(404, {ERROR: 'Page not found.'});
});

// 500: Error reporing
app.use(function(err, req, res, next){
    console.error(err.stack);
    res.json(500, {ERROR: 'Internal server error.'} );
});

// Startup new server
app.listen(900);
```

**routes/something.js**

```
var something = require(__dirname + '/../controller/something.js');

module.exports = function(app) {
    app.get('/v1/something', function(req, res, next) { new something().getAll(req, res, next); });
};
```

**controller/something.js** (I'd like to use the same logger for debug logging)

```
/**
 * Constructor
 *
 */
function Something() {
};

/**
 * Get all the data
 *
 */
Something.prototype.getAll = function(req, res, next) {
    // I want to log some very important information here
    res.json({result: true, data: ['hello', 'hi', 'ciao', 'buf']});
}

module.exports = Something;
```

The other thing I am thinking about is logging all the events in functions that are called from controllers (e.g. models or other libraries).

So I think, the good way might to create some logger library, that will be called using:

```
var logger = require(__dirname + '/../libraries/logger.js');
```

containing logger definition. The other issue I don't know how to solve is how to prefix data. You know, I have a lot of concurrent requests and I'd like to see which debug message was called by each request.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

We use [winston](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston), it's probably the most robust logging package out there.

We ended up setting it up exactly like you suggested. Creating a common library used for wrapping the logger object around our definitions and transports, and then handling any other type of objects we want to be handled differently.

https://gist.github.com/rtgibbons/7354879

Edit: Aug 2023 - Update Winston link to the new repo location

Comment: Do you log to a file or to a database?

Comment: currently we log to a file. Using logrotate to manage old logs. We are testing out using the Loggly transport

Comment: Winston Library hasn't been updated since its last release in August 2021, in fact. I recommend you pino library (https://www.npmjs.com/package/pino).

Comment: @ArielRuiz I still use Winston, the project has moved into it's own Github org now.

Answer (score 15):

If you're using express you may want to look at [express-winston](https://github.com/heapsource/express-winston) package. Then you can use  winston as middleware and easily log requests/errors without making your code messy...

Comment: Thanks, I found this earlier and I can see it as very useful. However,  it's easy to use it as http request logger, but I'd like to use it inside the application as well.

Comment: You can pass your own logger to express-winston:  `app.use(expressWinston.logger({ transports: [ myLogger ] }));`

Comment: expressjs is now equipped with **morgan** module by default. when you trigger an `express-generator` call

Answer (score 8):

I love the following Rails-style logging:

```
[2017-11-02T11:13:54.545 #07738a81] Started GET /api/url for 10.0.0.1
[2017-11-02T11:13:54.550 #07738a81] Completed 200 31739 in 5.635 ms
```

The code below does it

```
addRequestId = require('express-request-id')(setHeader: false)
app.use(addRequestId)

morgan = require('morgan')
morgan.token('id', (req) -> req.id.split('-')[0])

app.use(morgan(
  "[:date[iso] #:id] Started :method :url for :remote-addr",
  immediate: true))

app.use(morgan("
  [:date[iso] #:id] Completed :status :res[content-length] in :response-time ms"))

app.use('/api', router)
```

Comment: Reader beware, this is Coffeescript (slim arrow)

Answer (score 2):

I love [Hirung103](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19835652/whats-the-best-practice-for-expressjs-logging#47074065) answer, so here is the javascript version:

First, add [express-request-id](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-request-id) and [morgan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/morgan) if those libs not listed in your `package.json`.

Then add these lines inside your `server.js`:

```js
...
const addRequestId = require('express-request-id')({
  setHeader: false
})

app.use(addRequestId)

const morgan = require('morgan')

morgan.token('id', (req) => {
  req.id.split('-')[0]
})

app.use(
  morgan(
    "[:date[iso] #:id] Started :method :url for :remote-addr",
    {
      immediate: true
    }
  )
)
...
```

thanks to [Hirung103](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3676469/hirurg103)